Convert xml.etree.ElementTree.Element to lxml.Element
I'm developing a package that can be used by both users of lxml and the default xml package. ATM I have a small try:except for the lxml import, but sometimes the user uses functions like dump() from the default xml.etree which don't support the lxml.Element.
How can I convert between lxml Element and default Element in an efficient way without passing through a string or doing custom recursive processing?

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24650370/407651.

As original author of the pandas' read_xml and to_xml, I supported both XML libraries by essentially using class objects with a base class XMLParser of common methods that etree and lxml classes extended to carry different methods. Conditional logic raised errors on unsupported methods.

@Parfait isn't that a bit of a maintenance hell? I mean, the modules don't change too often and are quite stable I suppose but still...

By the way, lxml supports dump(), see https://lxml.de/1.3/api/lxml.etree-module.html

Also, it might help to take a look at https://lxml.de/compatibility.html

XML libraries are very stable (etree being part of Python's standard library) and we use core parsing methods not any novel features.

@Hermann12 yeah, one of the problems is a mismatch, not the fact that dump does not exist. For instance, you use the default dump and the code works, but then the user installs a third party library, which depends on lxml, and then my library automatically shifts to lxml which breaks his code. That's just one example of many issues.
